# Getting the handle of Google Chrome's "+" Add Tab button from C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, tabs, handle

I am trying to override the action of the "+" button that adds a new tab with website shown as  thumbnails with the action, "Opening a new website", say "www.google.com".

I googled on getting the handle of that button, so that I can get a feedback in my application when that button is clicked and I can open that website as a new tab.

I do not now if this is this only/best way of doing it.

Some help would be appreciated.

I am aware of the method of opening a page in application via C# i.e

```
Process.Start("chrome", @"http://www.google.com/");
```

But doing it at the right time is what I am looking for.

**QUESTION**

***I want to get the handle of the "Add New Tab" button of google chrome,so that I can understand when its clicked and run my code accordingly.***

> Edit
>
> > Chrome_WidgetWin_1

I found that this is the parent class that contains the button. So is there any way of identifying it as to which button it is and getting a handle of it ?

Regards
Priyabrata

Comment: This question is vague.add more details and be specific of what you want.

Comment: I want to get the handle of the "Add New Tab" button of google chrome.

Comment: Try Microsoft Spy if you really insist on taking this path; you could also look in the Chrome source code and figure out where/how they build the controls you're interested in. My advice: build a Chrome extension, if possible.

Comment: Here extension is not an option, and I must do it from an external application. What are the other alternatives to extension that I can take ?

Comment: Are there any constant key_codes that can be used to detect it using the parent class of chrome ?